# Lost trying to make the rspec test pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec2

I have this class:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iq
  validates :name, presence: true

  def genius?
    iq >= 3
  end

  def self.genius
    where("iq >= ?", 3)
  end
end
```

And I am making the rspec test:

```
describe Zombie do
  context "with high iq" do
     let!(:zombie) { Zombie.new(iq: 3, name: 'Anna') }
     subject { zombie }

     it "should be returned with genius" do
       Zombie.genius.should include(zombie)
     end

     it "should have a genius count of 1" do
       Zombie.genius.count.should == 1 
     end
  end
end
```

I am having this error message:

```
Failures:

1) Zombie with high iq should have a genius count of 1
Failure/Error: Zombie.genius.count.should == 1
expected: 1
got: 0 (using ==)
# zombie_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) '

Finished in 0.2138 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec zombie_spec.rb:10 # Zombie with high iq should have a genius count of 1
```

I am using the syntax: `let!(:zombie){...}` but it is telling that got 0 when I expected 1. Any idea? Maybe I have passed a lot of time looking to this code and I don't see where is the problem.

Comment: Are you actually trying to test the count of the Zombie, rather than the genius? e.g. `Zombie.count.should == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Zombie.create` instead of `Zombie.new`.

Also, the `should` syntax is deprecated:

```
specify ".genius returns an array of zombies" do
  expect(Zombie.genius).to include(zombie)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line

```
let!(:zombie) { Zombie.new(iq: 3, name: 'Anna') }
```

should be

```
let!(:zombie) { Zombie.create(iq: 3, name: 'Anna') }
```

Why?  Because *create* ensures the zombie instance is saved to the database so when you do a query for an iq >= 3, you get back a zombie.  *new* only keeps the zombie instance in memory I believe.